# I can’t make an array formula work with this in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to turn this formula into an array that carries down the whole column.

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Form Responses 2'!G:G,MATCH(C2&D2,'Form Responses 2'!D:D&'Form Responses 2'!E:E,0 )))`

Google Sheets offers to ‘autofill’ the formula down the column, but that stops working as new rows are added (as new form submissions come in).

(Using autofill, the formula on the next row is:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Form Responses 2'!G:G,MATCH(C3&D3,'Form Responses 2'!D:D&'Form Responses 2'!E:E,0 )))`

I’ve tried every way I can think of to make this an array.  Nothing has worked so far.

[The 1st image is the tab ‘Form Responses 2’][The 2nd image is the tab ‘Form Responses 1’]

[1st Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stnf0.png)
[2nd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVwXN.png)

Comment: INDEX(... MATCH(  type formulas do not work in ARRAYFORMULA() there are lots of different options for how to get the result you want, but my guess is that you could most easily use a VLOOKUP() inside the ARRAYFORMULA.  Try restructuring your formula as a VLOOKUP() and it should work

Comment: I need to match 2 criteria.  Will VLOOKUP allow that?

Comment: yes.  Structure it similarly to your INDEX/MATCH.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3:C&D3:D,{'Form Responses 2'!D:D&'Form Responses 2'!E:E,'Form Responses 2'!G:G},2,0)))

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.` [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)